# What does MariaDB do at midnight?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Does MariaDB do anything in particular at midnight and lasts for 1.5 hrs?

I've noticed this over the past week that mysqld uses 100% CPU and 75% RAM usage slowing down the rest of my applications.

Looking at the current connections there is no slow queries or similar happening at this time.

This is 50GB InnoDB database with >2500 tables

What can I do to troubleshoot what is going on at this time of day? The rest of my application grinds to halt and critical processes cannot work fast enough as mysqld hogs the resources.

Thanks,

Comment: Sounds like a backup (there normally disable slow query log), but it could be [events](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/show-events/). Maybe a logrotate scripts? Or is another cron based process occurring? Suggest looking at `SHOW PROCESSLIST` as a SUPER user at that time and identify the resource consuming queries. What distro/MariaDB version?

Comment: The version is `10.3.10-MariaDB-1:10.3.10+maria~xenial`. I'll look into what you have suggested, `SHOW PROCESSLIST` as the root user didn't show anything abnormal. Ty

Comment: could also try turning on the general query log for a brief period if nothing shows in the `show processlist`.

Comment: There is the `lograte` midnight cron job. In `/etc/lograte.d` there is a `mysql-server` task which includes the `mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf --local flush-error-log \
              flush-engine-log flush-general-log flush-slow-log` command. Is this a heavy command?

Comment: have disabled this cron job for tonight, will see if the issue stops

Comment: This `logrotate` script was designed to be light (avoids binary log and other heavier flush commands). Do you have general query log enabled? Is general or slow query log going to a table? You could force a `logrotate -f /path/to/mysql-server.conf` to see if it cases troubles at another time. Disabling the cron also works.

Comment: Okay it was not the logrotate cron job.. Issues still happend at approx midnight. Will need to checkout general query log now

Comment: @danblack , still nothing jumping out at me in terms of queries. I watched `processlist` as the root user when the problem started tonight and there are no abnormal queries, no locks, no slow queries that might be a `mysqldump` etc. I have quickly massed 0.5GB of general log in a little over an hour which will make fun reading. I'm really confused with this one

Comment: general query log - would be a rough look to compare to other times of day, the point would be to catch a number of tiny queries that didn't occur at other times what would of escaped a general processlist look. Apart from that a good monitoring system that watches a broad range of mariadb and IO statistics and see if you can identify a number of outlying statistics and come up with conclusion (or avenue for further investigation).

Comment: If I told you that when the problem starts and CPU goes to 100% and RAM more less gets maxed out - I restart the mariaDB service - once it loads up again it instantly repeats the issue and uses all the resources again. Would that offer any greater insight? I've searched the general log many times and I'm 99% sure its not a query that is doing this to the database. Seems to be some sort of nightly process. Something particular to InnoDB?

Comment: Dan, I have a theory that it is a PHP script that runs hourly (would explain why it wont happen when apache is off). The problem occurs between 1am and 2am. The script in question contains a lot of `WHERE dataInsertDate >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR) ORDER BY id ASC `  and the same for `INTERVAL 24 HOUR `

Does using this sort of DATE discrimination like this around 1am have any problems?

Answer (score 2):

Hi user1202278 (is that your real name?),

MariaDB does not perform any particular scheduled actions on its own.  There is almost certainly a cron job at work, unless there are users who stay up late every night!

It would be a good exercise to monitor your DB for a while and see how often and when heavy processes are running.  From there, you can narrow down the suspects.  If you haven't already, I would recommend that you invest a good monitoring tool.  I personally use [Navicat Monitor for MySQL/MariaDB](https://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat-monitor).  It provides all of the important stats on the Dashboard page and can track server metrics such as disk usage, I/O, CPU, RAM, etc.

It has a 14 day trial, which should be plenty of time to diagnose your issue.

Best of luck!

Comment: I'll look into that tool. The hunt continues, so far I've traced it down to Apache. When the apache service is stopped across midnight to 1.30 the problem does not happen. When apache is on, you can expect the problem to start bang on schedule

Comment: have you looked what web requests you get in this timeframe. Are they excessive in number or on less commonly used pages?